# Etags fails to understand access modifiers for PHP

Tags: php, etag

I was trying to generate etags for PHP class files and realised that it doesn't comprehend access modifiers (private/protected/public) and 'static' keyword in front of function declarations! For example, if the file contents are:

```
<?php
class Foo {
  public static function doBar() {}
  protected function isBaz() {}
}
```

Running `etags -l php` on the file will only result in `class Foo` being recognised. If I drop the keywords in front of `function`, it recognises the function names correctly.

Does anyone know of a solution for getting etags to identify PHP tags correctly?

Comment: Well, you need to update your `etags` thingy then, or rewrite it to support the modifiers.

Answer (score 2):

use exuberant ctags with '-e' option.

```
find . -name \*php | xargs ctags -e -f TAGS --language-force=php
```